# What can I expect from Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I am brand new to this site. It has a reputation of being hard on the enthusiast programmers. I would like to start off on the right foot so I would appreciate it if the members would kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/21960)

Answer (score 5):

I think that any "reputation of being hard on the enthusiast programmers" will prove unfounded for those on any SE site that:

1. Take its Tour e.g. the [Tour for Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour);
2. Familiarize themselves with the site's On-topic page e.g. the [On-topic page for Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); and
3. Familiarize themselves with the site's Asking page e.g. the [Asking page for Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

***before*** asking their first question on that site.

Another very valuable resource to consult as you get further into using a site is its whole Help Center (e.g. the [Help Center for Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)) and beyond that the nuances of each site can be found in additional guidelines and a myriad of other advice at its Meta site.  Note that this site (Meta SE) is its own Meta.

Answer (score 3):

As with any community - there's a certain "social contract" people expect off a new site.

I suspect the first, most important thing is really to spend a little time looking around, and getting to know the site. In addition to the [very extensive set of guides that @PolyGeo has linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306625/215590), I've found that spending a little time *passively* using a site helps.

Get to know search (so you aren't starting off posting duplicates), and try to work out what sort of questions are well received on a site. Work out what the community 'tacitly' expects in good posts while you're looking around.

Personally I've found folks who post good answers are often very good at posting good questions - so I'd recommend picking a question in your field of interest and posting the *best answer you can*. Then work towards posting one better. That way, when you post a question, you know what the folks answering need to help you.

Basically as with any community - it is easier when you work out *their* ways than expecting it to work like, say a forum.

We're strange, but we can also be wonderful.

Comment: After reviewing the Meta Stack Exchange it has become very apparent that is no place for me. Just by looking at posts and reviewing profiles it is easy to tell this is a closed group. The same people continual show up in the comments sections on questions asked, yet their profiles do not show same involvement when it comes to asking and answering questions.  It reminds me of the poem “The Road Not Taken” by Robert Frost and what my father used to say about the road less travelled. "When you have two roads, look for crap. If you see crap, that's the one donkeys took."